# MySQL conditionally create a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to do a conditional create table in MySql based on the result of a select statement? Essentially, if I have a schema used by multiple clients but only some of them need a table can I create it based on another value...for example...if I have a user John then Create this table...because John's app needs it.

Something along the lines of:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name='JOHN')

CREATE TABLE CREATE_THIS
   (
        ID VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
        NAME VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL   
    )
    ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of business logic does not really belong within the database layer of your application.  It would normally reside at a higher level, within whatever code you use to connect to the database.

However, for completeness, there is a (very hackish) way to accomplish what you ask by preparing a statement from a string that contains the SQL to be executed:

```
SET @sql := CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name='JOHN') THEN
 'CREATE TABLE CREATE_THIS (
    ID VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL   
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
END;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: This works in the case where select resolves.  But I'm getting an error in the prepare statement when @sql is null.  Is there a way to do a check for this?

Comment: I used an else statement to set the @sql to a select that I know would return empty.  This does seem a bit hackish.  I will take you advice under consideration to put this logic elsewhere.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```sql
    CREATE Table IF NOT EXISTS <Table_Name> ( ....
    ...)
```